# ROC curve - the plot does not show as it is expceted

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, roc

I am trying to plot a ROC curve graph using pyhton matplotlib library. I want to display the curve line as a dish line with a marker as the one showed in the picture below:
[image: Figure1]
Figure Ref: https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2019.12.21.885491v1.full

This is my code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(test_Y, predict_proba)
auc = roc_auc_score(test_Y,y_pred)
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='%s (AUC = %0.2f)' % ("LR", auc),marker='h',linestyle='--')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1],'r--',label='No skills')
plt.xlim([-0.02, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 1.02])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate (%)')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate (%)')
plt.title('ROC Curve')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.grid()
```

This is the plot that I have got:

[image: Figure2: my plot]

It seems as if something went wrong as the 'marker' printed on the whole line.
If I removed the marker parameter from the plot function, I got this:

[image: Figure3]

I do not really know why this might happen. Is is something wrong with the way I plotted the graph, or it might be the issue with the model results.

Could anyone please help me out with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markers are used at every data point passed in. Do you want to plot the whole curve but display markers at only every e.g. 10 points? If so try this:

```
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, linestyle='--')
plt.plot(fpr[::10], tpr[::10], marker='h')
```

Comment: Thanks Julien for your answer. Yes, want plot the whole curve but display markers at only some points. I have just tried what you suggested but I still got the same graph as the second one above.

Comment: Well it shouldn't, maybe you have a lot lot of points and you want to print every 100th instead of 10th? If it's still not working share a [mcve]...

Comment: Thank you very much @Julien, all good now. Really appreciate it.